# Tangent contour line path between pairs of fields

Tags: differential-geometry, parametric, vector-fields

Say you have two maps of hills with a single peak each which have contour lines which are concentric rings of various shapes. Superimpose these maps on a single piece of paper so the contour lines intersect. Now starting at the top of one hill, make a path down the hill following the gradient tangent to the contour line.

But also make sure that you are simultaneously going up the other hill tangent to *its* contour lines. In other words you are tracing a path where the contour lines of one map are tangent to the contour lines of the other.

You will draw a unique path from the top of the hill on the first map to the hill on the second map.

Given two height functions $\phi_1(x)$ and $\phi_2(y)$ how can one construct the equation for that curve relating the heights of both maps $f(\phi_1,\phi_2)=0$? Is there a general method? (exclude any pathological cases). Is there any books about this?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options, but let's say a fairly straightforward approach is to calculate the two gradients 
$$\nabla \phi_1(x) = \left(\frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial x_1}(x), \frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial x_2}(x)\right) \, \text{ and } \, \nabla \phi_2(x) = \left(\frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial x_1}(x), \frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial x_2}(x)\right)$$ and look for all points $x = (x_1, x_2) \, \in \, \mathbb{R}^2$ for which the angle between the two gradients $\nabla \phi_1(x)$ and $\nabla \phi_2(x)$ is $\pi$.

The dot product formula at any arbitrary point $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ gives
$$\big( \, \nabla \phi_1(x) \cdot \nabla \phi_2(x) \, \big) = |\nabla \phi_1(x)| \, |\nabla \phi_2(x)| \, \cos{(\theta(x))}$$ where $\theta(x)$ is the angle between the gradient vectors $\nabla \phi_1(x)$ and $\nabla \phi_2(x)$ while $|\nabla \phi_1(x)| = \sqrt{\big( \, \nabla \phi_1(x) \cdot \nabla \phi_1(x) \, \big)}$  and $|\nabla \phi_2(x)| = \sqrt{\big( \, \nabla \phi_2(x) \cdot \nabla \phi_2(x) \, \big)}$ are the lengths of the gradient vectors. For all points $x = (x_1, x_2) \, \in \, \mathbb{R}^2$ for which the angle $\theta(x)$ between the two gradients $\nabla \phi_1(x)$ and $\nabla \phi_2(x)$ is $\pi$ the value of $\cos{(\theta(x))} = -1$ so the condition becomes

$$\big( \, \nabla \phi_1(x) \cdot \nabla \phi_2(x) \, \big) = - |\nabla \phi_1(x)| \, |\nabla \phi_2(x)|$$ which is the same as the equation for a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$

$$F(x_1, x_2) = \big( \, \nabla \phi_1(x) \cdot \nabla \phi_2(x) \, \big) + |\nabla \phi_1(x)| \, |\nabla \phi_2(x)| = 0$$

Another option would be to take the determinant equation

$$\Delta(x_1, x_2) =  \begin{vmatrix}
\, \frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial x_1}(x_1, x_2) \,  &  \, \frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial x_2}(x_1, x_2) \, \\
\, \frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial x_1}(x_1, x_2) \,  &  \, \frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial x_2}(x_1, x_2) \, \\
\end{vmatrix} = 0$$ and take only the solutions where the two gradients oppose each other (the other solutions will have the two gradients pointing in the same direction)